# Avoid changing variables globally

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple exercise: `x` is a column of data.frame `dt`. I want to make a Shiny app that prints out the mean of the `x`. If the checkbox "multiply by 2" is selected then multiply `x` by 2. If not then the old value.

```
library(shiny)
dt <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rep(c(2,3),5))

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("myCheckbox", "multiple dt$x by 2"), 
  actionButton("myButton", "show result")
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  i <- 0

  observeEvent(input$myCheckbox,{ # if this checkbox is true then dt$x should be muiltiplied by 2
    i <<- i + 1
    if(i > 1){ # first call should not change dt$x
      if(input$myCheckbox){
        dt$x <<- dt$x * 2
      }else{
        dt$x <<- dt$x / 2
      }
    } 
    })

  observeEvent(input$myButton,{
    showNotification(paste0("Mean of dt$x is equal ", mean(dt$x)), type="default")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I avoid those `<<-` ? It is risky and in my bigger Shiny app with 300 lines of code I sometimes get an error that says R cannot select the scope.

Comment: Do you want to be able to multiply `dt$x` multiple times? or just toggle between multiplying it by two and back to its original values?

Comment: toggle. As we see in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reactiveValues` function for reactive programming:

```
library(shiny)
dt <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rep(c(2, 3), 5))

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("myCheckbox", "multiple dt$x by 2"),
  actionButton("myButton", "show result")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(x = dt$x)
  observeEvent(input$myCheckbox, {
    if (input$myCheckbox) {
      values$x <- values$x * 2
    } else {
      values$x <- values$x / 2
    }
  })
  observeEvent(input$myButton, {
    showNotification(paste0("Mean of dt$x is equal ", mean(values$x)), type = "default")
    print(dt$x)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The `reactiveValues` function returns an object for storing reactive values. It allows you to avoid changing the variables globally, which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

define a reactive version of `dt` in the server function. You can use multiple input values to define the reactive expression. Another option would be to set a `reactiveValues()` object and update it with observers, but I think the `reactive()` expression is better suited for this case. If the value you are trying to define is determined entirely by current input values. If you wanted to manipulate it iteratively with the app, then `reactiveValues()` might be better.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
dt <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rep(c(2,3),5))


ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("myCheckbox", "multiple dt$x by 2"), 
  checkboxInput("myOtherCheckbox", "set dt$x to 0"),
  actionButton("myButton", "show result")
)


server <- function(input, output){
  dt2 <- reactive({
    mutate(dt, x = if(input$myCheckbox==TRUE){2*x} else{x}) %>%
    mutate(x = if(input$myOtherCheckbox==TRUE){0}else{x}
  })

  observeEvent(input$myButton,{
    showNotification(paste0("Mean of dt$x is equal ", mean(dt2()$x)), type="default")
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: but what when I want to rearange dt$x many times with many buttons? What if I want to add second reactive on the same x like : `dt2 <- reactive({
    if(input$myCheckbox2 == TRUE){mutate(dt, x = 0)} else {dt}
  })`

Comment: probably put it all in the same reactive expression. You can define it based on multiple input values